# bootstrap grid when mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

In full screen I didn't want to use `grid` and  I want to display 7 and I want to manage image  2,2,2,1  when It in mobile

how can I do something like this ...

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <img src="banner1.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <img src="banner1.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
</div>
```

In my html which look nice but when mobile How can i display 2,2,2,1

```
<div class="container banner">
      <img src="banner1.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
      <img src="banner2.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
      <img src="banner3.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
      <img src="banner4.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
      <img src="banner5.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
      <img src=banner6.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
      <img src="banner7.png" alt="" class="banner-img">
    </div>
```

Comment: actually Im not clear your question,can you please explain

Comment: Now I've 7 images which look nice but I didnt use any col , when mobile It look bad how can I display  2 , 2 ,2 1 when mobile @core114

Comment: @test1321 can you share your ruuable code snippet via fiddler or other tool? Btw I understand your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mdd9yn79/ .

Comment: here is my code How can I  want to display use col-xs-6 when mobile but when full screen I want to look something like this https://jsfiddle.net/mdd9yn79/

Comment: do you want to use `col-*` classes?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt, nope his requirement is different. Check my answer below for that

Comment: @VicJordan I am asking to OP because his question is not clear till now. And for your answer...have you checked it in mobile view...OP is saying fro 2 2 2 1 structure.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt yes I Have already checked on mobile view

Comment: using `col-xs-6` met his requirement I guess. Just confuse the last standing alone image, is it need to be centered or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to play with **CSS**. In Css use `@media` and set the banner width for **mobile screen**. Below is fully working example:

```css
.banner {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.banner-img {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .banner-img {
    width: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="container banner">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" class="banner-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can adjust banner width based on the screen size. Enjoy!

Comment: ok so the requirement is that the last image must be centered also ?

Comment: @MinhDuc, no. Requirement is that `on mobile screen it should display in 2, 2, 2, 1 format`. In your question on mobile screen it will not display in this format

Comment: I checked it in my browser and it worked perfectly as his requirement. I'm quite sure `col-xs-6` is just triggered when on mobile screen.

Comment: @MinhDuc, your code screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Ttd9h    

Now here is my code screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/QlNVx

Upvote my answer if you understand the difference ;)

Comment: Hmm it's strange. Here is my result that I see in my screen and browser: https://imgur.com/bJ5JDUG. Anyway, I think I need a look around to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually pointed out your own solution

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   img{
    border:1px solid black;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container banner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="banner-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The newest release of Bootstrap 4 is beta 3. Is there some reason why you use such an old release?

Comment: @Klooven Honestly, this is in my old project and I just use it to test for solution so I did not make change the version of bootstrap. However, I believe my answer still works the same with Bootstrap 4 beta 3.

Comment: @MinhDuc this is not the correct answer. Check my answer above

Comment: In beta 3 `col-xs` is just `col` :)